# How to bind a fxml file into a custom dialog box in scalafx?

Tags: fxml, scalafx

I am trying to create a custom dialog box in scalafx.I have an fxml file which contains all the text fields for the dialog box. Now I need to bind to the dialog box from the controller file where I have written the methods. How to do this?

Comment: There's a [_ScalaFXML_](https://github.com/vigoo/scalafxml) library that assists with using FXML files with _ScalaFX_. I've not used it, so I can't say too much about it, but I believe that will support the kind of things you're looking to do.